# Нужно ли явно наследовать дескрипторы от object (python)?

Tags: python, ооп, наследование, дескрипторы

Должен ли класс дескриптора быть явно унаследован от класса object? Видел многие примеры кода, где люди именно дескрипторы наследуют явно, python3.. (но почему??)

```
class Grade:
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {} 
 
    def __get__(self, instance, instance_type): 
        if instance is None: 
            return self 
        return self._values.get(instance, 1) 
 
    def __set__(self, instance, value): 
        if not (1 <= value <= 5): 
            raise ValueError('Оценка должна быть от 1 до 5') 
        self._values[instance] = value
```

Comment: нужно ли в python 3.. явно наследовать класс дескриптора от object? Видел несколько примеров кода где именно класс дескриптора наследуется явно, остальные классы наследуют по умолчанию (без указания object). Не понимаю почему так делают.

Comment: Это наследие от python2. Не только про дескрипторы, а в целом классы создавали, указывая явно `object`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/5909792

Comment: Про 2й python я в курсе, но вопрос именно про 3й. И примеры кода с указанием явного наследования именно классов дескрипторов видел на python 3. Может есть какие-то нюансы?

Comment: Написал же: наследие питона2. Наследовать от object в питоне3 не нужно. По ссылке, что привел выше, есть пример в `Python 3.x story:`, что разницы теперь нет - указывать `object` или нет, все-равно, классы по умолчанию от него наследуются :)

Comment: Спасибо. Я это знаю ) Вопрос задал, чтобы развеять сомнения по поводу классов дескрипторов в python3.

Comment: @Иван_Нижний_Новгород Тогда можете ответить на собственный же вопрос

Comment: @nomnoms12 подожду, вдруг у кого то есть еще мнения на этот счет. А также спустя какое то время я смогу убедиться что иначе быть не может.